# Google Sheets: Click button to unhighlight row, highlight the next row, and update cell with date and time button was clicked

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to create a rotation scheduler. My goal is to have a table of names, phone numbers and a button.

When the button ('Assign') is pressed, it highlights a row, and updates a cell outside the table with the date & time it was clicked. When it is pressed again, it un-highlights that row and highlights the next row, and updates the date/time cell.

When it reaches the bottom, it should move back to the top. It should save where it left off between closing and opening the document and it needs to sync even when several users have it open... I don't think Excel can do that, but Google Sheets should be able to, which is why I'm leaning towards Google Sheets.

I completely understand if that's too much to expect someone to sort out on a forum, but I would very much appreciate even a point in the right direction as to figuring it out myself!!

Answer (score 1):

> When the button ('Assign') is pressed, it highlights a row, and
>   updates a cell outside the table with the date & time it was clicked.

You can add or create an image that acts as a button and associate a script to be [triggered when it is clicked](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/).

> When it reaches the bottom, it should move back to the top.

One way of doing it is to keep track of the highlighted row and use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to wrap back to the start of the table.

> It should save where it left off between closing and opening the
>   document

One option is to use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store the highlighted row.

I tried to implement a sample using these ideas (make a copy before you run): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bHN5cf2HaLTW3EbAxfXUusQnDL3dNFY313J8cdTGp4o/

The associated script:

```
var NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNEES = 5;
var LAST_ASSIGNMENT_DATETIME_CELL = 'G3';
var TABLE_OFFSET = 2;

function assignNewPerson(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  setAssignTime(sheet);
  assignNext(sheet); 
}

function setAssignTime(sheet) {
  var d = new Date();
  sheet.getRange(LAST_ASSIGNMENT_DATETIME_CELL).setValue(d.toLocaleTimeString());
}

function assignNext(sheet) {
  // Use the Properties Service to store the current assignee index.
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var currentAssigneeIndex = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('CURRENT_ASSIGNEE_INDEX'));
  if (isNaN(currentAssigneeIndex)) {
    currentAssigneeIndex = 0;
  } 

  // Remove highlight from assignee cells.
  sheet.getRange(TABLE_OFFSET + currentAssigneeIndex, 1, 1, 2).setBackground("white");

  // Increment the assignee index. If the last row is reached, go back to the start of the table.
  currentAssigneeIndex = (currentAssigneeIndex + 1) % NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNEES; 
  documentProperties.setProperty('CURRENT_ASSIGNEE_INDEX', currentAssigneeIndex);

  // Highlight assignee cells.
  sheet.getRange(TABLE_OFFSET + currentAssigneeIndex, 1, 1, 2).setBackground("yellow");
}
```